# Jquery Post two Array AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs

Im trying to send two Arrays on my AngularJS app but i get "404 URL Not Found". Is this ok? What am i missing?

My AngularJS code:

```
$scope.Guardar = function () {
    if (confirm('¿Está seguro de guardar los datos?')) {
        $("#btnGuardar").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $scope.MostrarMensajeOk = false;
        $scope.MostrarMensajeError = false;

        var nombreRegla = $("#lblNombreRegla").val();
        var localesEnGrilla = $("#localesGrilla").val();//array1
        var articulosEnGrilla = $("#articulosGrilla").val();//array2

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: baseURL + 'Configuracion/CrearRegla/',
            data: { "Nombre": nombreRegla, "Locales": localesEnGrilla, "Articulos": articulosEnGrilla, "CurrentUser": userName }
        }).success(function (result) {
            if (result != null) {
                $("#btnGuardar").prop('disabled', '');
                $scope.MostrarMensajeOk = false;
                $scope.MostrarMensajeError = false;

                $scope.volver();
            }
        });
    };
};
```

And my Controller :

```
 public void CrearRegla(string Nombre, string Locales, string Articulos, string CurrentUser)
    {
        //staff
    }
```

The error that give me is "404 not found URL"

Answer (score 0):

"404 URL Not Found" means that's `url` not valid.

Make sure that's `baseURL` end with `/` and for `'Configuracion/CrearRegla/'` try without `/` like this `'Configuracion/CrearRegla'`

Comment: Yeah, i've been trying that but not work... if i do 
`Configuracion/CrearRegla/?Nombre=' + nombreRegla + '&Locales=' + localesEnGrilla + '&Articulos=' + articulosEnGrilla + '&CurrentUser=' + userName`
It says "`'Multiple parameters ('Locales' and 'Articulos') can not be linked to the content of the request.`" and crash. The problem its the way to send this two arrays. BaseURL its not the poblem because ive been use on other functions and works perfectly